# Access results of SQL Server stored functions in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a few stored functions in SQL Server that return a table via a select statement. Like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[mFunSelectStudents] ()
RETURNS @result TABLE
    (IDStudent int, 
     Name nchar(50),
     Password nchar(50))
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @result select * from School.dbo.Student
    RETURN    
END
```

I tried to assign the function to an SqlDataAdapter in c# like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("mFunSelectStudents", con);
SqlDataAdapter adpStudents = new SqlDataAdapter();
adpStudents.SelectCommand = cmd;
```

But this doesn't work..

Where `@result` is a return parameter of the stored function. Now, how do I call the function in C# and assign the data to a grid ?

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: I have tried that but it still didn't work.. I think I have to access the @result parameter somehow..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command cannot be just the name of the function. You are supposed to put a SQL command there, and in SQL one retrieves data from a TVF by SELECTing from it, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.mFunSelectStudents()
```

Consequently, the first line of your C# code snippet should be:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.mFunSelectStudents()", con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the function in a stored procedure, or do the work itself in a SP. The results of a single select statement will be accessible as a DataTable in the C# client.

```
      create proc  selectSomeData
       .
       .
       .
```

In the client, your commandType would be StoredProcedure and the CommandText would be the name of the sp.

Comment: I must call stored procedures/functions from C#(it's a requirement). Stored procedures can only return scalar values, so I must use stored functions. There has to be a way to do that..

Comment: @bullFrog: Actually stored procedures can return rowsets too. If you issued a SELECT in your stored procedure, the result set would be returned to the calling application (to your application as well as any other one).

Comment: @bullfrog: stored procedures can indeed return result sets too, as I said, the result of a single select statement issued in a SP is exposed as a DataTable client-side.  So either wrap the function in a SP, or simply forget the function altogether and issue the select statement in the SP.

Answer (score -1):

Your first line :

> SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("mFunSelectStudents", con);

Is correct, however this one you should check it

> SqlDataAdapter adpStudents.SelectCommand = cmd;

First you need to use new with the SqlDataAdapter before you can assign the selectCommand, as follows:

```
SqlDataAdapter adpStudents = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

Assign the command to the DataAdapter

```
adpStudents.SelectCommand = cmd;
```

And then you prepare a Dataset

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

Fill it with your DataAdapter

```
adpStudents.Fill(ds);
```

Assign it to your grid

```
gridName.DataSource = ds;
```

And call DataBind to update the info on the grid

```
gridName.DataBind();
```

Comment: I have called the `SqlDataAdapter adpStudents = new SqlDataAdapter()` before, but I haven't copied it.. sorry..

Comment: if you are going to use the data adapter the new SqlDataAdapter(cmd) would work better, mostly because that way you take your query from the cmd object